# How to Run Two applications on single JBoss without creating multiple instance

Tags: jboss

I have one application which listen to 1099 port.
I also have another application which refer to same port(1099).
I have deploy this two application in single JBoss.
When i run JBoss(Using jboss-6.1.0.Final) it throws an error.
Is there any other way to do this without creating another instance of JBoss?

Answer (score 1):

Two processes should not be listening to the same port. You should make the ports configurable in the applications, and then use different ports for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can you provide me an example to make port configurable and to use different ports ?